# How can I force UIAlertView to display the full message without scrolling when in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7, uialertview

I have an app that prompts a user for input using a UIAlertView. The app is locked in landscape mode so the space that the UIAlertView has to grow in size is limited. In iOS 5 and 6, the two UIAlertViews I created were able to display their titles and messages without forcing the user to scroll inside the UIAlertView to see the full message.

[image: 1st Alert in iOS 6. Notice that no scrolling is required.]

[image: 2nd Alert in iOS 6. Notice that no scrolling is required.]

However, in iOS 7, the exact same alerts (meaning the text remained the same), the user has to scroll to display the full message. Here are the alerts as displayed in iOS 7:

[image: 1st Alert in iOS 7. Notice that the full message is not displayed.]

[image: 2nd Alert in iOS 7. Notice that the full message is not displayed.]

Interestingly enough though, there is enough room to display the full message in at least the 1st alert. Below is an image of the 1st alert after being scrolled a little.

[image: 1st Alert in iOS 7. This screenshot shows that the full message does fit in the alert view.]

In the second alert view, the whole message does not fit, even after scrolling, because the message takes up two lines. However, in iOS 6, the message took up only one line.

[image: 2nd Alert in iOS 7. This screenshot shows that the full message does not fit in the alert view, even after the user scrolls.]

My questions are:

1. In the case of the second alert, why does the message display on two lines in iOS 7 and how can I prevent that from happening?
2. How can I force UIAlertView to display the full message without scrolling when in landscape mode?
3. Why did the behavior of UIAlertView change in iOS 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It displays on 2 lines because with the new iOS7 style it doesn't fit. There is increased padding, and even without the padding, the new iOS 7 dynamic type kit font sizes prevents you from having any sizing guarantees.
2. You can't, not without making your own custom UIView, making it look similar but decreasing the padding and locking the font sizes.
3. The style of the whole OS changed. Although I am surprised they increased the padding so much. I guess with the dynamic font sizes they weren't too worried about keeping backward compatible layouts.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So from what I understood, the padding is not an accessible property, meaning I can't just change it to fit the content? Also, it's not possible to keep the iOS 6 Alert View style in iOS 7 without creating a custom one, correct?

Comment: @Mickster37 yep, correct (for both questions). Maybe its time for a design rethink - perhaps a modal popup VC with these required fields and validation messages inline.

Comment: Tyson, can you think of any custom UIView out there that fits my needs or can you give me any more guidance as to how I would do this? After considering my options, I'd prefer to do what you describe in #2 rather and presenting a modal VC.